# What is the PHP7 way to check if a value is set and is equal to a specific value?

Tags: php, php-7

What is the PHP7 method of the following function that checks if a value is set and equal to a specific value?

Let me know if you see any other room for improvement in general:

```
public function getResponseFormat($request)
{
    $responseFormat = 'php';

    if(isset($request['controller']['name']) && $request['controller']['name'] == 'email') {

        if(isset($request['controller']['options']['responseFormat'])) {

            $responseFormat = $request['controller']['options']['responseFormat'];
        }
    }

    return $responseFormat;
}
```

Comment: *What is the PHP7 way* Exactly how you do it

Comment: It looks like the second isset could become: 

$responseFormat = $request['controller']['options']['responseFormat'] ?? 'php';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make use of the new NULL COALESCE operator, you can write the method like this:

```
public function getResponseFormat($request)
{
    if ($request['controller']['name'] ?? null == 'email') {
        return $request['controller']['options']['responseFormat'] ?? 'php';
    }

    return 'php';
}
```

`$x ?? null` evaluates to null if $x is not set, and `$x ?? 'php'` evaluates to 'php' if $x is not set.

You could also put everything in one line with an additional ternary operator `?:` to have a single `return` but that would be at the cost of readability.